# Chrome doesn’t show un-minified code in spite of source map present

Tags: google-chrome, source-maps, uglifyjs

I’m using Grunt and UglifyJS to generate source maps for my AngularJS app. It produces a file `customDomain.js` and `customDomain.js.map`.

#### JS file

Last line of `customDomain.js` looks like this:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=customDomain.js.map
```

#### Map file

I find two references to `customDomain.js` inside of `customDomain.js.map`, one at the beginning:

```
"sources":["../../../.tmp/concat/scripts/customDomain.js"]
```

I think this looks weird so I trim it to:

```
"sources":["customDomain.js"]
```

The second reference is at the end:

```
"file":"customDomain.js"
```

...which I leave as it is.

#### Testing

When I run my app in Chrome I expect to see my development code when I click on `customDomain.js`, but I do not:

[image: Chrome dev tools]

I can see on the console output from my web server that `customDomain.js.map` is indeed requested from the browser:

```
200 /js/customDomain.js.map (gzip)
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

`"sources":["customDomain.js"]` should be *relative* to the `customDomain.map.js` file. 
Make sure they are in the same directory on your server if this is the case for you.

`"file":"customDomain.js"` should be changed to the name of the map file, in your case this would be `"file":"customDomain.map.js"`.

Here's a map file example taken from [treehouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps) (`sourceRoot` may be unnecessary in your case):

```
{
    version: 3,
    file: "script.js.map",
    sources: [
        "app.js",
        "content.js",
        "widget.js"
    ],
    sourceRoot: "/",
    names: ["slideUp", "slideDown", "save"],
    mappings: "AAA0B,kBAAhBA,QAAOC,SACjBD,OAAOC,OAAO..."
}
```